# evt.ctrlKey returns false in jquery keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent

I am currently developing a web application that requires me to detect if control is pressed.

I use keydown event to set a flag to true if the pressed key is ctrl then keyup event to set that flag to false. I'm using `evt.ctrlKey` to easily return true if the key pressed is the control key.

But to my surprise, I can see that evt.keyCode is equal to 17 while `evt.ctrlKey` gives me a false.

This does not happen to keydown event.

Please see this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y6WL/) for reproduction. I'm using firefox 27.

PS : I know that I can just test if keyCode is 17 but I want to know if I missed something.

Comment: different events equal different keycodes indeed.

Comment: Did you find anything unusual to my posted fiddle? Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: its not wrong, the keyup did return false for the ctrlkey also. its just that different events have different states of the keys pressed. also, ctrlkey may be unreliable on different os

Comment: What exactly is not right? You said it yourself *I use keydown event to set a flag to true if the pressed key is ctrl then keyup event to set that flag to false* but then you changed your mind about this being wrong?

Comment: To complicate things even more: I have a standard keyboard with two Ctrl keys. If you hold both down, and release one, you also get `true` on `keyup` check. This might explain more what @Good luck replied with "ctrl is pressed" at the time of the event.

Comment: @Spokey what I'm asking if right or wrong is my understanding whether ctrlKey should really return false, because to my understanding it should return true since the cause of keyup is releasing control key. I don't get where I imply the "I changed my mind" part in your comment.

Comment: I thought that when you said  *keyup event to set that flag to false* you understood that by the time that event fires the ctrl key is not pressed anymore, since it fires when you let the key go (evt.ctrlKey returns the state of the button and keyCode returns which button was pressed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to w3c docs ctrlKey event attribute returns true if it's presse and false if not, so your code is working right. On keydown event ctrl is pressed - so it returns keycode 17 and true , on keyup ctrl is not pressed, so the result is 17 and false.

Comment: I'm actually looking [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MouseEvent-ctrlKey) and I'm confused with the meaning of "depress". I thought "depress" means opposite of "press" which is "release" (keyup). I then googled the meaning of it "depress" and it actually means "to push and cause to move down" which make sense to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `keyup` says:

> ctrlKey: `true` if the control key was down when the event was fired. `false` otherwise.

The keyup and keydown events are fired *after* the key has been pressed/released. So the state of `ctrlKey` is correctly `down` for the keydown event and `up` for the keyup event. More explicitly, the order is:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.
2. Keydown event is fired.
3. Release <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.
4. Keyup event is fired.

Furthermore, if you are looking for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key *itself* you should be checking the key code, not the `ctrlKey` property. The latter is for checking key combinations, for example if you want <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, you would check for a keyup/keydown event of `{ keyCode: 83, ctrlKey: true }`.